# Not able to login

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Im am trying to create a secure login form but for some strange reason, I am able to register new users (adds to mysql) but cannot login. When I try logging in, I see "Error Logging In!" Can someone please help me out?

**functions.php**

```
/*
* Copyright (C) 2013 peredur.net
*
* This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
* it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
* the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
* (at your option) any later version.
*
* This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
* but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
* GNU General Public License for more details.
*
* You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
* along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/

include_once 'psl-config.php';
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

function sec_session_start() {
$session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name 
$secure = SECURE;

// This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
$httponly = true;

// Forces sessions to only use cookies.
if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
    exit();
}

// Gets current cookies params.
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);

// Sets the session name to the one set above.
session_name($session_name);

session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}

function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
// Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt 
              FROM wpmq_app 
                              WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
    $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();

    // get variables from result.
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
    $stmt->fetch();

    // hash the password with the unique salt.
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
        // from too many login attempts 
        if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Account is locked 
            // Send an email to user saying their account is locked 
            return false;
        } else {
            // Check if the password in the database matches 
            // the password the user submitted.
            if ($db_password == $password) {
                // Password is correct!
                // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);

                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                // Login successful. 
                return true;
            } else {
                // Password is not correct 
                // We record this attempt in the database 
                $now = time();
                if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time) 
                                VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')")) {
                    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: login_attempts");
                    exit();
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // No user exists. 
        return false;
    }
} else {
    // Could not create a prepared statement
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: cannot prepare statement");
    exit();
}
}

function checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) {
// Get timestamp of current time 
$now = time();

// All login attempts are counted from the past 2 hours. 
$valid_attempts = $now - (2 * 60 * 60);

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT time 
                              FROM login_attempts 
                              WHERE user_id = ? AND time > '$valid_attempts'")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);

    // Execute the prepared query. 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    // If there have been more than 5 failed logins 
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 5) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else {
    // Could not create a prepared statement
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: cannot prepare statement");
    exit();
}
}

function login_check($mysqli) {
// Check if all session variables are set 
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['login_string'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password 
                  FROM wpmq_app 
                  WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        // Bind "$user_id" to parameter. 
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists get variables from result.
            $stmt->bind_result($password);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

            if ($login_check == $login_string) {
                // Logged In!!!! 
                return true;
            } else {
                // Not logged in 
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Not logged in 
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Could not prepare statement
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: cannot prepare statement");
        exit();
    }
} else {
    // Not logged in 
    return false;
}
}

function esc_url($url) {

if ('' == $url) {
    return $url;
}

$url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);

$strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
$url = (string) $url;

$count = 1;
while ($count) {
    $url = str_replace($strip, '', $url, $count);
}

$url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);

$url = htmlentities($url);

$url = str_replace('&amp;', '&#038;', $url);
$url = str_replace("'", '&#039;', $url);

if ($url[0] !== '/') {
    // We're only interested in relative links from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
    return '';
} else {
    return $url;
}
}
```

**process_login.php**

```
<?php

/*
* Copyright (C) 2013 peredur.net
*
* This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
* it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
* the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
* (at your option) any later version.
*
* This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
* but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
* GNU General Public License for more details.
*
* You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
* along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/

include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$password = $_POST['password']; // The hashed password.

if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
    // Login success 
    header("Location: ../protected_page.php");
    exit();
} else {
    // Login failed 
    header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
    exit();
}
} else {
// The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
header('Location: ../error.php?err=Could not process login');
exit();
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright (C) 2013 peredur.net
*
* This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
* it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
* the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
* (at your option) any later version.
* 
* This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
* but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
* GNU General Public License for more details.
* 
* You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
* along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
$logged = 'in';
} else {
$logged = 'out';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Secure Login: Log In</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/sha512.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
        echo '<p class="error">Error Logging In!</p>';
    }
    ?> 
    <form action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">          
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
        Password: <input type="password" 
                         name="password" 
                         id="password"/>
        <input type="button" 
               value="Login" 
               onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" /> 
    </form>
    <p>If you don't have a login, please <a href="register.php">register</a></p>
    <p>If you are done, please <a href="includes/logout.php">log out</a>.</p>
    <p>You are currently logged <?php echo $logged ?>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Added 'js' folder

forms.js

```
    function formhash(form, password) {
// Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
var p = document.createElement("input");

// Add the new element to our form. 
form.appendChild(p);
p.name = "p";
p.type = "hidden";
p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

// Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
password.value = "";

// Finally submit the form. 
form.submit();
}

function regformhash(form, uid, email, password, conf) {
 // Check each field has a value
if (uid.value == ''         || 
      email.value == ''     || 
      password.value == ''  || 
      conf.value == '') {

    alert('You must provide all the requested details. Please try again');
    return false;
}

// Check the username

re = /^\w+$/; 
if(!re.test(form.username.value)) { 
    alert("Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores. Please try again"); 
    form.username.focus();
    return false; 
}

// Check that the password is sufficiently long (min 6 chars)
// The check is duplicated below, but this is included to give more
// specific guidance to the user
if (password.value.length < 6) {
    alert('Passwords must be at least 6 characters long.  Please try again');
    form.password.focus();
    return false;
}

// At least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter 
// At least six characters 

var re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/; 
if (!re.test(password.value)) {
    alert('Passwords must contain at least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter.  Please try again');
    return false;
}

// Check password and confirmation are the same
if (password.value != conf.value) {
    alert('Your password and confirmation do not match. Please try again');
    form.password.focus();
    return false;
}

// Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
var p = document.createElement("input");

// Add the new element to our form. 
form.appendChild(p);
p.name = "p";
p.type = "hidden";
p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

// Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
password.value = "";
conf.value = "";

// Finally submit the form. 
form.submit();
return true;
}
```

hash = [http://pajhome.org.uk/](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha512.html)

Comment: check `function login($email, $password, $mysqli)`, echo messages in it. and trace from where it return `false`

Comment: Incorrect password. I tried the actual password typed by the user, the one stored in mysql and 'salt' nothing works.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.security.ini.php